# su without password with pam su-authentication

Tags: 14.04, password, authentication, pam, su

I've done the following configuration in ubuntu 14.04 but it's still asking password.

```
$ /etc/passwd

test:x:1004:1004::/home/test:/bin/bash

$/etc/pam.d/su

 auth       required   pam_wheel.so group=test
 auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
```

Is there any  other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## su to root without a password

In the file `/etc/pam.d/su` put this as the line:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_permit.so
```

To restrict this just to your username, use this line instead, replace the `yourusername` with your actual username:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = yourusername
```

You can also restrict this to a group, here the group allowedpeople can su without a password:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup allowedpeople
```

then login

```
su yourusername
```

Comment: you don't need the first line, if you include it, you will have paswordless root access from a regular user

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line in `/etc/pam.d/su` before:

```
auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = <username you want to su>
```

then,

To restrict this just to your username, use this line instead, replace the yourusername with your actual username:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = yourusername
```

to restrict access to group

```
auth            sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user ingroup allowedpeople
```

Comment: adding this line breaks root access, I can not longer `su` to root.